# FOP trimming spaces and tabs inside strings

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using fop libraries v1.1 to produce a pdf, and I noted that fop  by default collapse white-spaces **inside** strings. For example a block like:

```
<fo:block>
  Sample                   Text
</fo:block>
```

Render as

```
Sample text
```

eliminating whitespaces. I would like to keep strings inner whitespaces in the generated pdf, so I tried to use the `white-space="pre"` attribute inside the block tag, but it preserves only white-spaces outside the string.

Then I tried to use the `white-space-treatment="preserve"` attribute inside the block tag, but the rendered page had collapsed white-spaces.

Finally I tried to use the  `white-space-collapse="false"` attribute inside the block, and also in this case the rendered page had collapsed white-spaces.

Why fop is collapsing by default white-spaces **inside** strings?
Is there a way to change the fop behaviour in order to preserve white-spaces inside strings?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. `white-space="pre"` works for me. Can you please explain what you are doing in more detail? How are you creating the XSL-FO markup?

Answer (score 0):

`white-space="pre"` should work here or you may use `linefeed-treatment = "preserve", white-space-collapse = "false", white-space-treatment = "preserve", wrap-option = "no-wrap"` which are equal to `white-space="pre"`. For more information you may also visit http://www.learn-xsl-fo-tutorial.com/Blocks-Inlines.cfm#h1.6